# How do add process.env when using vite?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, vite

I got a react project I'm building with `vite`.
This project uses @mui and inside it, they have -

```
if (typeof process !== 'undefined' && process.env.GRID_EXPERIMENTAL_ENABLED !== undefined && localStorageAvailable() && window.localStorage.getItem('GRID_EXPERIMENTAL_ENABLED')) {
  experimentalEnabled = window.localStorage.getItem('GRID_EXPERIMENTAL_ENABLED') === 'true';
} else if (typeof process !== 'undefined') {
  experimentalEnabled = process.env.GRID_EXPERIMENTAL_ENABLED === 'true';
}
```

When they try and access `process.env.GRID_EXPERIMENTAL_ENABLED`, it fails, saying it can't get GRID_EXPERIMENTAL_ENABLED of undefined.

I logged `process`, and it's an empty object.

I tried different ways of generating a process env through the `vite.config.ts` file, but nothing worked.

**Expected result** - 3rd party libs should be able to access `process.env`

Answer (score 0):

Vite `define` configuration may replace js assets while bundling.

```js
export default defineConfig(({ command, mode }) => {
  return {
    define: {
      "typeof process !== 'undefined'": "true",
    }
  ...
```

replaces the 3rd party code "if condition" that checks whether `process` is defined or not to `true`

So you can make further changes like that. Please remember this define works as replacement in production bundle but not in dev mode.

https://v3.vitejs.dev/config/shared-options.html#define